# Java get all webpages(sitemap) for any website

Tags: java, html, sitemap

I want to get all webpages for a website for example for the bbc website(bbc.co.uk) it would get http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/, http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/ etc.

One way i can think of going about doing this is just start from the homepage and collect all the links and for each linked webpage on the homepage do the same collection. Essentially the final goal is to generate a sitemap for any website.

Does anybody have any other solutions which would be more efficient than this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can be used to achieve the same

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.load("http://bbc.co.uk");
// get all links from page
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElement link : links){
   // Store link and do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a free & open source sitemap generator written in java that you could modify here...

[Java-Open Source- SiteMap Generator Code](http://www.ucware.com/gsitemap/)

Comment: Any documentation for this? I can't seem to find any on the link provided.